# How do I implement Cross Domain URL Access from an Iframe using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I need to access the Parent Domain URL from my Iframe which is in another domain.

For example, "example.com" is my website which has an Iframe from another parent domain, such as "google.com". Here I need to access the parent domain URL from my example.com. That is, I need to get the URL "google.com" in my "example.com" domain. Moreover, the Parent domain cannot be hard coded.

What I tried was using the following code:

```
window.parent.location.href()
```

but this results in Access denied error. How do I implement this properly in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 35):

You can try and check for the referer, which should be the parent site if you're an iframe

you can do that like this:

```
var href = document.referrer;
```

Comment: This only works when you open the iframe for the first time. If you navigate within the iframe, the previous page will then be the referrer.

Answer (score 15):

You might want to take a look at these questions/answers ; they could give you some informations concerning your problem :

- [cross domain access in iframe from child to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702074/cross-domain-access-in-iframe-from-child-to-parent)
- [`<iframe>` javascript access parent DOM across domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291812/iframe-javascript-access-parent-dom-across-domains)
- [How to access parent Iframe from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935127/how-to-access-parent-iframe-from-javascript)

To make things short : accessing iframe from another domain is not possible, for security reasons -- which explains the error message you are getting.

The [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) page on wikipedia brings some informations about that security measure :

> In a nutshell, the policy permits
>   scripts running on pages originating
>   from the same site to access each
>   other's methods and properties with no
>   specific restrictions — but prevents
>   access to most methods and properties
>   across pages on different sites.
>
> A strict separation between content
>   provided by unrelated sites must be
>   maintained on client side to prevent
>   the loss of data confidentiality or
>   integrity.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the referrer, you can implement `window.postMessage` to communicate accross iframes/windows across domains. 
You post to window.parent, and then parent returns the URL.
This works, but it requires asynchronous communication. 
You will have to write a synchronous wrapper around the asynchronous methods, if you need it synchronous.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <!--
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">


    <link rel="start" href="http://benalman.com/" title="Home">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/code/php/multi_file.php?m=benalman_css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mt.js"></script>
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // What browsers support the window.postMessage call now?
        // IE8 does not allow postMessage across windows/tabs
        // FF3+, IE8+, Chrome, Safari(5?), Opera10+

        function SendMessage()
        {
            var win = document.getElementById("ifrmChild").contentWindow;

            // http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/18/postmessage-in-html5-to-send-messages-between-windows-and-iframes/


            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072902/dom-exception-12-for-window-postmessage
            // Specify origin. Should be a domain or a wildcard "*"

            if (win == null || !window['postMessage'])
                alert("oh crap");
            else
                win.postMessage("hello", "*");
            //alert("lol");
        }



        function ReceiveMessage(evt) {
            var message;
            //if (evt.origin !== "http://robertnyman.com")
            if (false) {
                message = 'You ("' + evt.origin + '") are not worthy';
            }
            else {
                message = 'I got "' + evt.data + '" from "' + evt.origin + '"';
            }

            var ta = document.getElementById("taRecvMessage");
            if (ta == null)
                alert(message);
            else
                document.getElementById("taRecvMessage").innerHTML = message;

            //evt.source.postMessage("thanks, got it ;)", event.origin);
        } // End Function ReceiveMessage




        if (!window['postMessage'])
            alert("oh crap");
        else {
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                //alert("standards-compliant");
                // For standards-compliant web browsers (ie9+)
                window.addEventListener("message", ReceiveMessage, false);
            }
            else {
                //alert("not standards-compliant (ie8)");
                window.attachEvent("onmessage", ReceiveMessage);
            }
        }
    </script>


</head>
<body>

    <iframe id="ifrmChild" src="child.htm" frameborder="0" width="500" height="200" ></iframe>
    <br />


    <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="SendMessage();" />

</body>
</html>
```

Child.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <!--
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">


    <link rel="start" href="http://benalman.com/" title="Home">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/code/php/multi_file.php?m=benalman_css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mt.js"></script>
    -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
        // Opera 9 supports document.postMessage() 
        // document is wrong
        window.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
            //document.getElementById("test").textContent = ;
            alert(
                e.domain + " said: " + e.data
                );
        }, false);
        */

        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage
        // http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/
        // http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/
        // http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/docs/files/jquery-ba-postmessage-js.html

        // .data – A string holding the message passed from the other window.
        // .domain (origin?) – The domain name of the window that sent the message.
        // .uri – The full URI for the window that sent the message.
        // .source – A reference to the window object of the window that sent the message.
        function ReceiveMessage(evt) {
            var message;
            //if (evt.origin !== "http://robertnyman.com")
            if(false)
            {
                message = 'You ("' + evt.origin + '") are not worthy';
            }
            else
            {
                message = 'I got "' + evt.data + '" from "' + evt.origin + '"';
            }

            //alert(evt.source.location.href)

            var ta = document.getElementById("taRecvMessage");
            if(ta == null)
                alert(message);
            else
                document.getElementById("taRecvMessage").innerHTML = message;

            // http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage
            //evt.source.postMessage("thanks, got it", evt.origin);
            evt.source.postMessage("thanks, got it", "*");
        } // End Function ReceiveMessage




        if (!window['postMessage'])
            alert("oh crap");
        else {
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                //alert("standards-compliant");
                // For standards-compliant web browsers (ie9+)
                window.addEventListener("message", ReceiveMessage, false);
            }
            else {
                //alert("not standards-compliant (ie8)");
                window.attachEvent("onmessage", ReceiveMessage);
            }
        }
    </script>


</head>
<body style="background-color: gray;">
    <h1>Test</h1>

    <textarea id="taRecvMessage" rows="20" cols="20" ></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The loading of the child iframe is not going to work in a mixed-mode environment. For example, the main page in https and the child page in an iframe (http).

Comment: @lmiguelmh: Correct - if it would, that would be a security bug and the browser would need fixing. What you could do in this scenario is A) Putting the child page in https, B) form-post from the iframe to the https page, on the https page you have web-sockets that get notified if a form-post arrives on the server. Alternatively poll in an interval of x seconds whether new data has arrived. If you assign the post a guid, then the child can JSONP-poll the https page (that should be allowed), asking for the answer by guid - poll until it gets it. Don't know if web-sockets could beUsed inThatCase.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. Scope the domain down (see document.domain) in both the containing page and the `iframe` to the same thing. Then they will not be bound by 'same origin' constraints.
2. Use postMessage which is supported by all HTML5 browsers for `cross-domain` communication.

Answer (score 0):

Good article here:
[Cross-domain communication with iframes](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes)

Also you can directly set document.domain the same in both frames (even

```
document.domain = document.domain;
```

code has sense because resets port to null), but this trick is not general-purpose.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
window.frameElement.ownerDocument.domain
```