# How to use JavaScript to access cross domain iFrame content?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I would like to use this code

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('message').value  += "\r\n\r\n[img]"+response+"[/img]";
```

It works fine for pages coming from the same domain, but not for sites from another domain loaded in the iFrame. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross Domain URL Access from Iframe using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378433/cross-domain-url-access-from-iframe-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

You can implement window.postMessage to communicate accross iframes/windows across domains.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <!--
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">


    <link rel="start" href="http://benalman.com/" title="Home">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/code/php/multi_file.php?m=benalman_css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mt.js"></script>
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // What browsers support the window.postMessage call now?
        // IE8 does not allow postMessage across windows/tabs
        // FF3+, IE8+, Chrome, Safari(5?), Opera10+

        function SendMessage()
        {
            var win = document.getElementById("ifrmChild").contentWindow;

            // http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/18/postmessage-in-html5-to-send-messages-between-windows-and-iframes/


            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072902/dom-exception-12-for-window-postmessage
            // Specify origin. Should be a domain or a wildcard "*"

            if (win == null || !window['postMessage'])
                alert("oh crap");
            else
                win.postMessage("hello", "*");
            //alert("lol");
        }



        function ReceiveMessage(evt) {
            var message;
            //if (evt.origin !== "http://robertnyman.com")
            if (false) {
                message = 'You ("' + evt.origin + '") are not worthy';
            }
            else {
                message = 'I got "' + evt.data + '" from "' + evt.origin + '"';
            }

            var ta = document.getElementById("taRecvMessage");
            if (ta == null)
                alert(message);
            else
                document.getElementById("taRecvMessage").innerHTML = message;

            //evt.source.postMessage("thanks, got it ;)", event.origin);
        } // End Function ReceiveMessage




        if (!window['postMessage'])
            alert("oh crap");
        else {
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                //alert("standards-compliant");
                // For standards-compliant web browsers (ie9+)
                window.addEventListener("message", ReceiveMessage, false);
            }
            else {
                //alert("not standards-compliant (ie8)");
                window.attachEvent("onmessage", ReceiveMessage);
            }
        }
    </script>


</head>
<body>

    <iframe id="ifrmChild" src="child.htm" frameborder="0" width="500" height="200" ></iframe>
    <br />


    <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="SendMessage();" />

</body>
</html>
```

Child.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <!--
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">


    <link rel="start" href="http://benalman.com/" title="Home">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/code/php/multi_file.php?m=benalman_css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mt.js"></script>
    -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
        // Opera 9 supports document.postMessage() 
        // document is wrong
        window.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
            //document.getElementById("test").textContent = ;
            alert(
                e.domain + " said: " + e.data
                );
        }, false);
        */

        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage
        // http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/
        // http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/
        // http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/docs/files/jquery-ba-postmessage-js.html

        // .data – A string holding the message passed from the other window.
        // .domain (origin?) – The domain name of the window that sent the message.
        // .uri – The full URI for the window that sent the message.
        // .source – A reference to the window object of the window that sent the message.
        function ReceiveMessage(evt) {
            var message;
            //if (evt.origin !== "http://robertnyman.com")
            if(false)
            {
                message = 'You ("' + evt.origin + '") are not worthy';
            }
            else
            {
                message = 'I got "' + evt.data + '" from "' + evt.origin + '"';
            }

            //alert(evt.source.location.href)

            var ta = document.getElementById("taRecvMessage");
            if(ta == null)
                alert(message);
            else
                document.getElementById("taRecvMessage").innerHTML = message;

            // http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage
            //evt.source.postMessage("thanks, got it", evt.origin);
            evt.source.postMessage("thanks, got it", "*");
        } // End Function ReceiveMessage




        if (!window['postMessage'])
            alert("oh crap");
        else {
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                //alert("standards-compliant");
                // For standards-compliant web browsers (ie9+)
                window.addEventListener("message", ReceiveMessage, false);
            }
            else {
                //alert("not standards-compliant (ie8)");
                window.attachEvent("onmessage", ReceiveMessage);
            }
        }
    </script>


</head>
<body style="background-color: gray;">
    <h1>Test</h1>

    <textarea id="taRecvMessage" rows="20" cols="20" ></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can if your browser have disabled security, for chrome it's

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security
```

Update: I'm surprised that people keep devoting it because they consider it harmful, so here I add some additional details for peoples who don't know basics of web security and still try to develop for it.

DON'T use this solution if

- you are using chrome plugins or apps which are not trusted by you, or
- you have opened other sites in the chrome, or
- you have some malicious chrome processes
- your site is using any external resources.

To make this solution completely safe, configure your firewall to block all connections except one to which you are making CORS connection.

Also, don't use this solution if your connection endpoint isn't trusted.

Comment: I would consider this very harmful and strongly advice to not use this approach.

Comment: @Nicky it is not harmful if you know what are you doing. But thanks for notice, I've added a disclaimer for those who may try cluelessly use this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net), it's an easy to use library that provides a unified API for several tricks used to enable cross domain messaging, ranging from postMessage to the FIM-trick as a last resort.
This is what is used by major services such as Twitter and Disqus.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10293604)

Comment: @DavidePastore - this is a very complicated matter, and the question is too open ended to be able to provide a succinct answer to.

Answer (score 1):

Due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions this is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, this falls under same origin policy, but there are some tricks that allow limited communication with the iframe.  Take a look at http://ajaxify.com/run/crossframe/

Comment: The fragment hack used in this is extremely slow and has loads of issues - easyXDM is a way better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is called the same origin policy, and prevents javascript accessing content across domains.