# DOM Exception 12 for window.postMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning to build Chrome Extensions, and I'm trying to follow one of the instructions in the official Guide [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication).

What I am trying to accomplish is:

1. background.js shows page action for targetted URLs.
2. Page action executes a script when clicked.
3. Executed script injects javascript on page.

So far, so good! I use the following script to inject into the page.

```
var injectJS = function(url, cb) {
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = url;
    if (cb)
        s.onload = cb;
    h.appendChild(s);
};
injectJS(chrome.extension.getURL('script/do_something.js'));
```

Now, I want the injected script to be able to communicate back to the extension.
It seems like what I am looking for is what's described in the documentation.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication

The problem is, when I try to do `window.postMessage` the console shows an error "DOM Exception 12".

---

Edit: The first problem running the sample code was solved.
The other error I get, from the smae code is from `port.postMessage`:

`Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object`

Here's the code:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect();

// Respond to messages from the injected script to collect results
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    if (e.source != window)
        return;
    if (e.data.type && (e.data.type == 'FROM_PAGE')) {
        console.log('Content script received: %s', e.data.text);
        port.postMessage(e.data.text);
    }
}, false);
```

Basically I'm trying to persist some data temporarily while a page reloads. The content script/injected script collects the data, and then loads the next page. The background script should hold the results until all the pages have been loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't confuse the `port.postMessage` in the contentscript.js example with `window.postMessage`.

[`port.postMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#type-Port) is a Chrome extension-specific API, intended to pass messages around within the extension, while [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) is a JavaScript method used for communicating with frames. The second argument to `window.postMessage` is required, and is used to validate whether the target is allowed to receive the message or not.

In your case, using a wildcard is probably sufficient, because you're sending a message from a page to itself:

```
window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the webpage!" }, "*");
                                                                           ^^^
```

Comment: Thank You, that was exactly it! I should have paid more close attention to the sample.

One more question, if you don't mind. Continuing on with the same code, the `port.postMessage` portion isn't working now. My listener script runs, and I log the data to verify that it does exist, but it's now saying that the port is closed.

Comment: Then one of the ends died. Can't tell the exact reason without seeing your code.

Comment: I updated the original post with some additional details, if that helps.

Comment: @MatthewLucas What about the other side of the channel?

Comment: Please excuse me, I clearly haven't had my coffee! That was the problem, I didn't add code on the background end at all. I literally started out by re-typing the code on the sample page, and it didn't even cross my mind to add that. Thank you for all your help!