# Disable javascript's domain restrictions in FF 7.0

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-domain, firefox7

I am developing a small html + JS app for my own use and being ability to access IFrame's content or opened windows' contect with Javascript would greatly improve my productivity.

Is it possible to disable the cross domain restrictions imposed by Firefox 7.0, so that I will be able to modify contents of what is displayed in an iframe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross Domain URL Access from Iframe using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378433/cross-domain-url-access-from-iframe-using-javascript)

Comment: have you read http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/ and http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ ?

Comment: @TJHeuvel nope, doesn't contain an answer to my question, plus it's the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember a similar issue a while ago in FF. This is worth a try:

There's a file in your user profile called prefs.js. On my machine its located:

```
C:\Users\simon\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\aoagj1zo.default
```

In the file are a bunch of lines like this:

```
user_pref("accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashBar", 0);
user_pref("app.update.lastUpdateTime.addon-background-update-timer", 1317146699);
```

Try adding this line:

```
user_pref("capability.policy.default.XMLHttpRequest.open", "allAccess");
```

You should probably close FF, edit this file, then reopen FF.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I made sure I restarted FF and the line was there but still, no difference.