# How to Access Elements in FancyBox iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

There is an iframe, opened in fancybox window.
The content of the iframe is external.
Is there a way to access this content and to change the style of one of the elements?

Comment: external iframe means another domain?

Comment: AFAIK , it is not possible because of cross domain access security

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378433/cross-domain-url-access-from-iframe-using-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the iFrame is on another domain you can't access it in any way due to browser restriction. This is called [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

One thing that can get around it is the greasmonkey extension for firefox (this has no actual utility, it's just to let you know this fact if you are interested)

Answer (score 10):

Since the iframe has contents from the same domain, access the iframe using `contents()` like this:

```
$('#fancybox-content iframe').contents().find('.selector')
```

Comment: In my case it was $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('selector'); but still, thank you!