# How to Make iframe 100% height according to its content

Tags: html, css, iframe

I had seen a lot of people asking how to make iframe 100% height. That can be easily archived using some CSS. It will make the iframe display 100% as relative to the device screen. But how to make iframe 100% height according to its content?

Here's my current code to make 100% iframe according to device screen:

```css
        iframe {
        display: block;
        background: #000;
        border: none;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
```

```html
    <iframe src="https://...">Your Browser Does Not Support iframes!</iframe>
```

The `allowfullscreen` and `position:absolute` didn't help except for crashing my site's template. This is the best I can do without crashing the primary CSS. Please help...

Edit: The iframe content is responsive using

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`

so preset height using javascript didn't work too. Perhaps is there a way of using height units instead?

`em`, `ex`, `rem` etc? Or make it a specific percentage of `vw`?

Comment: this actually works for me in the latest version of chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and Safari

Answer (score 31):

Just wanted to share my solution and excitement. It took me four entire days of intensive research and failure, but I think I've found a neat way of making iframes entirely responsive! Yey!

I tried a ton of different approaches... I didn't want to use a two-way communication tunnel as with `postMessage` because it's awkward for same-origin and complicated for cross-origin (as no admin wants to open doors and implement this on your behalf).

I've tried using MutationObservers and still needed several EventListeners (resize, click,..) to ensure that every change of the layout was handled correctly. - What if a script toggles the visibility of an element? Or what if it dynamically preloads more content on demand? - Another issue was getting an accurate height of the iframe contents from somewhere. Most people suggest using `scrollHeight` or `offsetHeight`, or combination of it by using `Math.max`. The problem is, that these values don't get updated until the iframe element changes its dimensions. To achieve that you could simply reset the `iframe.height = 0` before grabbing the `scrollHeight`, but there are even more caveats to this. So, screw this.

Then, I had another idea to experiment with `requestAnimationFrame` to get rid of my events and observers hell. Now, I could react to every layout change immediately, but I still had no reliable source to infer the content height of the iframe from. And theeen I discovered `getComputedStyle`, by accident! This was an enlightenment! Everything just clicked.

Well, see the code I could eventually distill from my countless attempts.

```js
function fit() {
    var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe.gh-fit")

    for(var id = 0; id < iframes.length; id++) {
        var win = iframes[id].contentWindow
        var doc = win.document
        var html = doc.documentElement
        var body = doc.body
        var ifrm = iframes[id] // or win.frameElement

        if(body) {
            body.style.overflowX = "scroll" // scrollbar-jitter fix
            body.style.overflowY = "hidden"
        }
        if(html) {
            html.style.overflowX = "scroll" // scrollbar-jitter fix
            html.style.overflowY = "hidden"
            var style = win.getComputedStyle(html)
            ifrm.width = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("width")) // round value
            ifrm.height = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("height"))
        }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(fit)
}

addEventListener("load", requestAnimationFrame.bind(this, fit))
```

That is it, yes! - In your HTML code write `<iframe src="page.html" class="gh-fit gh-fullwidth"></iframe>`. The `gh-fit` is a just fake CSS class, used to identify which iframe elements in your DOM should be affect by the script. The `gh-fullwidth` is a simple CSS class with one rule `width: 100%;`.

The above script automatically fetches all iframes from the DOM, that have a `.gh-fit` class assigned. It then grabs and uses the pre-calculated style values for width and height from `document.getComputedStyle(iframe)`, which always contain a pixel-perfect size of that element!!! Just perfect!

Note, this solution doesn't work cross-origin (nor does any other solution, without a two-way communication strategy like IFrameResizer). JS simply can't access the DOM of an iframe, if it doesn't belong to you.

The only other cross-origin solution I can think of, is to use a proxy like https://github.com/gnuns/allorigins. But this would involve deep-copying every request you make - in other words - you 'steal' the entire page source code (to make it yours and let JS access the DOM) and you patch every link/path in this source, so that it goes through the proxy as well. The re-linking routine is a tough one, but doable.

I'll probably try myself at this cross-origin problem, but that's for another day. Enjoy the code! :)

Comment: How to remove the fact of this left overflow? I'd see you put overflow:hidden css property but it still showing the overflow disabled

Comment: Maybe it's that my iFrame contains a Google Web App, but I still found it necessary to spec the height in my CSS.

Comment: This works just about perfect. Is there a way to make it work on browser resize as well?

Comment: The `iframe-resizer` library uses all these methods and a number of other techniques to keep an iframe consistently sized to it’s content.

Comment: If you want to use this with `sandbox`, you need to use `sandbox="allow-same-origin"`

Answer (score 13):

There is no CSS only way to set iframe height according to its content.
You need to use JavaScript to get iframe content height and then set as iframe height.

how to achieve this using JavaScript answered and well explained in the following questions:

1. [Make iframe automatically adjust height according to the contents without using scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)
2. [make iframe height dynamic based on content inside- JQUERY/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript/9163087)
3. [Resize iframe to content with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872394/resize-iframe-to-content-with-jquery)
4. [Adjust width height of iframe to fit with content in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)
5. [cross-domain iframe resizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606920/cross-domain-iframe-resizer?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had the iframe content height since I make the content, but it is a responsive iframe that means that the height varies with the width. So in Mac, it would be 100% responsive but on PC and mobile, it would be shorter. Unfortunately, none of these 5 javascript method works.

Comment: @AnthonyKung you will want to bind the function of setting the height to onload and to onresize. This way it will also activate it on resize. You might want to use some form of throttling though.

Answer (score 5):

Try to set `position` to `fixed`, like this:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position:fixed;
```

Or like this:

```
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
position:fixed;
```

Comment: Try to put at least a sentence to explain your answer.

Comment: 100% height & width fixed as per browser content.

Comment: I meant, in the answer. And explains a bit. And read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for answering but sadly it didn't work, I had tried this before after suggested by other posts. This makes the footer section floating in the middle of `iframe`.

Comment: I have no problem in IE11 but similar problem in Chrome.  For Chrome, I found "position:absolute" works better than "position:fixed" - it now scrolls with the page, as I require, rather than floating as Anthony Kung describes. However, the IFrame overlaps the section below it now :(  However, it feels like a step closer.

Answer (score -1):

```css
        iframe {
        display: block;
        background: #000;
        border: none;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
```

```html
    <iframe src="https://...">Your Browser Does Not Support iframes!</iframe>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

Assign your iframe to a custom id and then you will be able to set it to vw or vh.

```css
#myiframe {
    width:77vw;
    height:calc(77vw / 3);
}
```

```html
<div align="center"><iframe id="myiframe" src="https://g1.ipcamlive.com/player/player.php?alias=64512bbc49030&skin=white&autoplay=1&disableautofullscreen=1&disablevideofit=1" width="900px" height="300px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe></div>
```