# javascript redirect on parent

Tags: javascript, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirect parent window from an iframe action using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action-using-javascript)

I have a page with an iframe and in content of this iframe have a redirection on all window, how can I make this?

Tried:

`window.location.href = 'logged.html';`

I can get if the page is opened in a frame or a up?

```
 if(isiframe) window.top.location.href
```

--- solution ---

```
if($("#cboxOverlay", top.document).length > 0)
  if($("#cboxOverlay", top.document).css("display") != 'none')
    window.top.location.href = '{{ path('portada') }}';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are in the same domain you may use

```
window.top.location.href = 'logged.html';
```

Otherwise there are a lot of similar threads in stackoverflow:

[Cross Domain URL Access from Iframe using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378433/cross-domain-url-access-from-iframe-using-javascript/1378456#1378456)

[Redirect parent window from an iframe action using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

`window.top.location.href = "http://www.yourwebsite.com";` (but the IFrame and the top window must be on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect the "parent" ?

```
window.top.location = 'logged.html';
```

Comment: i can get if the page is opened in a frame or a up?  if(isiframe) window.top.location.href