# Get iframe data in parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross Domain URL Access from Iframe using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378433/cross-domain-url-access-from-iframe-using-javascript)

I want to get data from an iframe in the parent window. However, the problem is my iframe and parent is in cross domain with different ports.

How is it possible without entering anything in the iframe?