# Use the new Facebook Photo Viewer (gallery) from iframe app

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, photo-gallery, facebook-opengraph

I have an (iframe) app hosted on a tag on a Facebook Page. The app pulls (based on various conditions) photos from the albums of the page and displays them to the user. Is it possible to create "ajaxify" links on the photos so that when the user clicks on the photo, the photo will open in the new Facebook Photo Viewer (lightbox overlay) without navigating to the actually photo's URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook's lightbox isn't part of the facebook api. You will have to implement your own lightbox, or download one from somewhere, to get this effect.

Comment: I was thinking of a more hackish way, such as triggering some facebook function from within the iframe. There might be same-origin issues, though.

Comment: This isn't possible if you don't own both domains. This may be of use to you for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702074/cross-domain-access-in-iframe-from-child-to-parent